# Find all places which start with and end with given phrase and add a special sign to the beginning of each occurrence in VS Code

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

Let’s start with an example. I want to find all the places, in the whole solution which start with the phrase `template` and ends with `.js`. 
e.g.
Match:

```
template\blah\loadprojdata.js
template\scripts\showhidecontrols.js
template\scripts\pageloader.js
template\scripts\andsearchfield.js
```

Don’t match:

```
template\scripts\pageloader.css
\template\scripts\andsearchfield.js
```

To all of the occurrences I want to add a \ sign to the beginning so the expected result would look like:

```
\template\blah\loadprojdata.js
\template\scripts\showhidecontrols.js
\template\scripts\pageloader.js
\template\scripts\andsearchfield.js
```

So far, I’ve created an expression

```
^template.*\.js$
```

But I have no idea how to add the `\` to the beginning of each line that was found. I have only an option of Replacement in The VS Code. Any ideas? 
Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may replace using

Find: `^(template.*\.js)$`
Replace: `\\$1`

The `(template.*\.js)` is a capturing group with ID 1 and its value is referred to with the `$1` placeholder from the replacement pattern. To replace with a literal `\` it should be doubled.

[image]

[image]

Comment: @GoldenAge Did you enable `pcre2` option?

Comment: Yes, I did. I also made sure if the settings.json which is located under the .vs folder, in the directory of the project contains a  { "search.usePCRE2": true
} Don't have any idea why it doesn't work

Comment: @GoldenAge [I have it working](https://imgur.com/a/akJH4J7) and the only changed setting is PCRE2 option.